# Why python decorator will lose func attribute __doc__?

Tags: python, decorator

```
def decor(fun):
    def living(*args, **kw):
        return fun(*args, **kw)
    return living

@decor
def test():
    '''function doc'''
    pass

print test.__doc__
```

why the result is `None`? Something happened when I use decorator? Thanks to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you wrap a function in a decorator:

```
@decor
def test:
```

you get back *the function created by the decorator*, (`living`, in this case) which doesn't have the same docstring, etc. It doesn't "lose" this data, `living` never had it!

You can get around this with [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
from functools import wraps

def decor(fun):
    @wraps(fun)
    def living(*args, **kw):
        ...
    return func
```

---

A quick demo to prove the point:

```
>>> def wrapper(f):
    def func(*args):
        """The wrapper func's docstring."""
        return f(*args)
    return func

>>> @wrapper
def test(x):
    """The test func's docstring."""
    return x ** 2

>>> test.__doc__
"The wrapper func's docstring."
```

versus

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def func(*args):
        """The wrapper func's docstring."""
        return f(*args)
    return func

>>> @wrapper
def test(x):
    """The test func's docstring."""
    return x ** 2

>>> test.__doc__
"The test func's docstring."
```

Comment: Thank you! When using decorator, the currently running function will becomes (`living`, in this case) and run `test()` in it. Is that right?

Comment: Yes - that's correct - `@decor` is shorthand for `test = decor(test)`

Answer (score 0):

That's because your decorator is basically replacing your function. You need to use [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to store the decorated functions internals like `__name__` and `__doc__`.

You can test this easily by adding a docstring to your decorator function `living()`:

```
>>> def decor(fun):
...     def living(*args, **kw):
...         """This is the decorator for living()"""
...         return fun(*args, **kw)
...     return living
... 
>>> @decor
... def test():
...     """function doc"""
...     pass
... 
>>> test.__doc__
'This is the decorator for living()'
```

Example from the docs of [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) which saves the wrapped functions name and docstring.

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def my_decorator(f):
...     @wraps(f)
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
...         print 'Calling decorated function'
...         return f(*args, **kwds)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> @my_decorator
... def example():
...     """Docstring"""
...     print 'Called example function'
...
>>> example()
Calling decorated function
Called example function
>>> example.__name__
'example'
>>> example.__doc__
'Docstring'
```